# How to install Zend Framework 2 Tool with composer

Tags: php, frameworks, zend-framework2

I can't figure out how to run zf.php (Zend Framework 2 Tool) when bootstrapped with composer.

First I bootstrap composer and zftool according to the documentation:

```
$ mkdir tmp && cd tmp
$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ ./composer.phar require zendframework/zftool:dev-master
```

This works fine so far.

But when I try to run zf.php, I get errors:

```
$ vendor/zendframework/zftool/zf.php 
PHP Warning:  require_once(/Users/seb/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zftool/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/seb/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zftool/zf.php on line 13

Warning: require_once(/Users/seb/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zftool/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/seb/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zftool/zf.php on line 13
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/Users/seb/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zftool/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/local/lib/php') in /Users/seb/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zftool/zf.php on line 13

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Users/seb/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zftool/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/local/lib/php') in /Users/seb/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zftool/zf.php on line 13
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using PHP 5.3.21 on Mac.

I also tested it on my Debian VServer with PHP 5.4, same error :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should copy zf.php into your root directory and run it from there.

```
$ mkdir tmp && cd tmp
$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ ./composer.phar require zendframework/zftool:dev-master
$ cp vendor/zendframework/zftool/zf.php .
$ php zf.php
```

Comment: That was the missing step, I wonder why they didn't mentioned in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: They really should add it to the documentation

Comment: This should REALLY be in the documentation. The docs even go so far as making you believe you don't have to do this.

Comment: Sorry I'm late, it should be in the docs, and I wish I could plus 2

Comment: Thank you! You just saved my day ! The same as Justin E. :)

Answer (score 5):

**Install Composer.phar locally**

If you do not have the composer globally installed on your machine, you can install it locally in the project.

Installing Composer locally is a matter of just running the installer in your project directory (https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

**Note**: If the above fails for some reason, you can download the installer with php instead:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

**Install ZF2**

```
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git --recursive
cd ZendSkeletonApplication
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```

**Install ZFTools (Installation using [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/))**

```
php composer.phar require zendframework/zftool:dev-master
php composer.phar install
```

**Create a symbolic link**

zf.php (Zend Tool) will be installed in the vendor/bin folder. You may run it with php vendor/bin/zf.php.

```
ln -s vendor/zendframework/zftool/zf2.bat zftools
chmod +x zftools
./zftools
```

In this case, I prefer symbolic link, for updating the zftools repository, I do not need to copy the file again.

**Without installation, using the PHAR file**

Another alternative to using the ZF tools, without creating scripts or aliases, and download the PHAR format.

```
wget https://packages.zendframework.com/zftool.phar --no-check-certificate
php zftool.phar  version
ZFTool - Zend Framework 2 command line Tool
The ZFTool is using Zend Framework 2.2.4
```

Or you can download [zftool.phar](https://packages.zendframework.com/zftool.phar) and use it.

Note 1:The @**akond** response is very good, I'm just presenting an alternative answer I like to use.

Note 2: This example was done on a windows machine using cygwin.

**Good tutorial installation (ZF2 and ZF3)**

[Getting started: A skeleton application](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/skeleton-application/)

Ref:

[Zend Framework Tool (ZFTool)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html)